# Jquery filter method for elements not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which contains ***hundreds*** of **checkboxes**, I need to make some of them to be checked.

I am **getting** checked **value from server**.

To filter them out and make them checked I do the following:

### JavaScript/jQuery

```
var userChangeProcess = function(object){

    console.log("userChangeProcess called", object);//1 object i am getting

    $.each(object, function(key,value){
        if(value.hasOwnProperty("Add")){
            console.log(value["Add"]);//i am getting 4 names of value
            var userLocales = $(':checkbox',"form").filter(function(){ 
                return $(this).val() === value["Add"] ? $(this).prop("checked",true).parent().addClass("green") : "";
            });
        }

    })
```

I also tried doing it this way (*without success*):

```
$(":checkbox[value='"+value["Add"]+"']","form").parent().addClass("green");
```

It's not working. what is wrong in my function?

Comment: What's in your `object`?

Comment: it has the country names

Comment: Try `$('input[type="checkbox"]',"form")` instead of `$(':checkbox',"form")`

Comment: sure, let me try for this way.

Comment: What is `$(':checkbox')`? You should use `$('input[type="checkbox"])` instead.

Comment: that is equivalent of 'input[type="checkbox"]' see here http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to accomplish by setting the var userLocales? If you're just trying to check a box and add a class, you could use some form of the following:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]', "form").filter(function(){ 
    return $(this).val() === value["Add"]
}).prop("checked",true).parent().addClass("green")
```